# Getting verification from LDAP through WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am only getting started with WSO2 Identity Server.

What do I need?
- getting verification from LDAP server that user (entry) is existing there through WSO2 Identity Server.

Is it possible? Can I do this by adding a new identity Provider in https://localhost:9444/carbon/?

Any ideas or help.

Sorry, if my question is dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity server comes with an embedded LDAP server as its primary userstore. But you can change [userstore configurations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+User+Stores) so that IS works with your LDAP too. You also can add your LDAP as a [secondary userstore](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+Secondary+User+Stores) as well.

After that, if you go to `User and Roles` section in UI, you should see Users and Roles existing in your LDAP.

Comment: Thanks for response. Will try it tomorrow.

Comment: I need something like 'Federated Authenticators'. For example, we have user that is not known to WSO2, and then WSO2 is just forwarding and getting verification from LDAP that user is existing there. And then I need (RESTful) API  that will give a token for authorization.

Comment: I have added secondary users store to IS. How can I do authentication using new USER and PASSWORD from LDAP? Can I generate token through RESTful API or something else?

Comment: You can create a service provider and configure oauth2 application. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+Inbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider
then you can call token api to get oauth2 tokens. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Resource+Owner+Password+Credentials+Grant

Comment: If you want to secure your REST APIs with OAuth2 and manage them, you can use WSO2 API Manager too. http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/
It provides OAuth2 token based security for your REST APIs out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter. This helped me a lot.

Comment: I will be really grateful if you @Bhathiya  look at my next question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749152/cross-domain-ajax-requests-wso2-is . ) And in any case, thank you.