# Cross-Domain Ajax Requests WSO2 IS

Tags: ajax, rest, wso2, cors, wso2-identity-server

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client id:client secret value>" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
```

(from  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Resource+Owner+Password+Credentials+Grant
)

This 'curl' command works perfectly. But when try to call it through ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic  Z0hLUlA3eThYTmJydl9JR1pJemxDQ1VJQlo0YTozT2VLaUlmUVViMk1yZzZ2YU5uQVFsWFpDU29h'
      },
      url: 'https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
    };
```

I got this error: *"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."*


 How can I configure WSO2 IS to deal with it? Or is there an alternetive for this?

There is  a similar issue with WSO2 API Manager ([WSO2 API Manager CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305316/wso2-api-manager-cors)). But there is no such directory '/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/' in WSO2 IS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour when cross origin resource sharing (CORS) is not enabled on Identity Server. In fact you can enable CORS for Identity Server. Check [1] on how to do it.

[1] http://hasanthipurnima.blogspot.com/2016/05/applying-cors-filter-to-wso2-identity.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Token API of IS returns CORS headers. To get this working, you can front Token API of IS by API Manager. By default, APIM returns CORS headers in all REST APIs you create in it.

In fact, API Manager ships an API (i.e. `https://localhost:8243/token`) which fronts the token API of IS (i.e. `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token`) (note: APIM has certain IS features installed in it). But it does not return CORS headers too. To make it return CORS headers, you should follow that SO link you have mentioned.

Another simple option is, if you only need CORS headers, you can simply front Token API of IS by another custom services which returns CORS headers in the response.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.