# How do you add the CORS headers to wso2identity carbon?

Tags: cors, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working on some prototyping and trying to execute a call against the SCIM rest interface from within a JS page.. yes, I know its not secure, this is purely some proof of concept stuff, so this ins't a problem...

What is a problem is that the wso2 carbon doesn't have the CORS headers as part of its response etc. so it won't let the javascript interact with the web service... I don't see anything in the documentation on how to turn these on with wso2 carbon... I assume there must be a way to do this... does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this post](http://hasanthipurnima.blogspot.com/2016/05/applying-cors-filter-to-wso2-identity.html).

You can read more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749152/cross-domain-ajax-requests-wso2-is).